# Tools to Debug WCF service

Tags: wcf, testing, tcptrace-pocketsoap

What are the tools available to debug WCF service?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by debug. Certainly there are a lot of tools that are useful when dealing with WebServices and WCF specifically, besides the obvious use of the Visual Debugger or WinDBG. Here are some:

- [WCF Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx)
- [Service Trace Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx)
- TCP monitoring tools, like [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) or TCP tunnels like [TcpTrace](http://www.pocketsoap.com/tcptrace/) or [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

Answer (score 0):

If its runtime hang or crash debugging, check out http://blogs.msdn.com/Tess/

Answer (score 0):

1. Attach via visual studio.  As long as you dont have express edition you can use Visual Studio to attach to WCF services.  That would be step 1.
2. Use the message logging.
   [WCF Admin and Diagnostics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731859.aspx)
3. Use the tracing
   [WCF Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730342.aspx)